# Get id button clicked

Tags: android, click

In my android app I need to create some TextView not in xml file but in a for cicle. When i click one of the TextView that i've created in the for cicle i need to get the id of the textview clicked. I write this code, but it give me an error when i click on the textview:

```
//inside for cicle
TextView txtv = new ChiamataView(getApplicationContext());
txtv.setId(i);
txtv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 60));
txtv.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray));
txtv.setText(json_data.getString("Codice"));
txtv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
txtv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        var id = v.getId();
});
```

I've also tried to cast ((textView) v).getId(); but it doesn't work.
How can I do?
Thanks, Mattia

Comment: What exactly is the error? My first thought is that v.getId() returns an int, so try altering the line in the onClick() method to `int id = v.getId();`

Comment: what ID are you looking for and what do you need it for? The most common use for IDs on android is to look up a reference to a View with a call to findViewById(R.id.someview). Since you've created your view with java this would be unneeded. So what other purpose do you have for the view ID? surely whatever you're trying to accomplish could be done in some other way.

Comment: Yes it is int, i don't know why i wrote var. How can i show the error in eclipse? In logcat it say runtime error

Comment: Each textview corrisponde to a record taken from a database. The textview id is the same id of the database record

Comment: Can you post the log cat error?

Comment: I solved using the textview text, thanks anyway!